# How to change login screen resolution on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: login, 20.04, screen, display-resolution

I use an LG Electronics 34" monitor, but the resolution is set by default to 1920x1080. I can set to 2560x1080 by adding the following lines in my .profile.

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.76  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync >/dev/null 2>1
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2560x1080_60.00>/dev/null 2>1
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1080_60.00 >/dev/null 2>1
```

I want to set the login screen resolution to 2560x1080.